# длинная загрузка после splash Image - Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Android. При старте показываю логотип на белом фоне, 2 секунды, а дальше наблюдается белый экран 4 секунды, и запускается сцена, проверял в пустой сцене, запускается сразу после логотипа игра, слышал как-то запускают пустую сцену а дальше загружают сцену игры или асинхронно загружать в момент показа логотипа, подскажите как это сделать лучше, если можно объясните как это реализовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш вопрос очень общий и смешивает несколько независимых подходов, которые решают разные задачи.

То что описываете вы, обычно, используется для загрузки внешних ресурсов. В случае с мобильными платформами это практически всегда AssetBundle, скачиваемый с удалённого сервера.

В вашем случае проблема в длительности загрузки самой сцены. Предполагаю, что все ресурсы у вас под рукой. Вы не предоставили никакой информации, и сложно оценить насколько сцена валидна. Возможно, она до предела перегружена объектами или использует нехорошие скрипты, тормозящие загрузку.

Но так или иначе, загрузку сцены можно сделать асинхронной. Для этого служит метод [`SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html).

По ссылке же находится пример, демонстрирующий корутину с примером использования.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        //Press the space key to start coroutine
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            //Use a coroutine to load the Scene in the background
            StartCoroutine(LoadYourAsyncScene());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator LoadYourAsyncScene()
    {
        // The Application loads the Scene in the background at the same time as the current Scene.
        //This is particularly good for creating loading screens. You could also load the Scene by build //number.
        AsyncOperation asyncLoad = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("Scene2");

        //Wait until the last operation fully loads to return anything
        while (!asyncLoad.isDone)
        {
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Экземпляр [`AsyncOperation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AsyncOperation.html) содержит свойство [`progress`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AsyncOperation-progress.html), которое позволяет отражать процедуру загрузки в различных ProgressBar'ах.

Вы можете реализовать любую анимацию или просто крутящуюся картинку на чёрном фоне, которая будет висеть перед глазами игрока до окончания загрузки сцены. Тоже самое касается и прочих асинхронных операций.

Обрати внимание, что ожидание завершения операции `while (!asyncLoad.isDone)` должно выполняться итеративно в отдельной корутине, порождённой методом [`StartCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!  я скрывал все объекты и результат тот же, то есть  скрипты не выполнялись, поэтому скорее сцена перегружена объектами